# Overcoming dimension errors with matrix multiplication?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I'd like to multiply two matrices (to be clear I want it in the linear algebra meaning of the word, i.e., if you want further clarification of what I mean see this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Matrix_product_.28two_matrices.29)) I've tried `A * B` (which I got by following the MATLAB to Numpy guide at [Scipy Wiki](https://web.archive.org/web/20150818181140/http://wiki.scipy.org/NumPy_for_Matlab_Users)) but when `A` had dimensions of (N-1)x(N-1) and `B` had dimensions of (N-1)x(N+1) it gave out the ValueError (where `N=100`):

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (99,99) (99,101)
```

I also tried `np.dot(A,B)` in case I was unintentionally using an array (ps. this could be the case, as I do have a few np.asarray commands for the vectors I built A and B from. How do I convert them to matrices?) and not a matrix and got the same result.

This is my code in full (granted A and B are replaced by `np.diag(xasub)` and `np.sin...`, respectively and this is on the `d2Tsub` line)

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.special as sp

N = 100
n = range(0,N+1)
xmin = -10
xmax = 5

pi = np.pi
x = np.cos(np.multiply(pi / float(N), n))

xa = np.asarray(x)
xasub = xa[1:N]

xc = (1+xa)*(xmax-xmin) / float(2)
xcsub = xc[1:N]

na = np.asarray(n)
nd = np.transpose(na)

T = np.cos(np.outer(np.arccos(xa),nd))
Tsub  = T[1:-1]

from numpy import linalg as LA

dT = np.sin(np.outer(np.arccos(xa),nd))*na
dTsub = dT[1:-1]

d2Tsub = np.diag(np.power((xasub*xasub-1),-1)) * (Tsub*nd - np.diag(xasub) * np.sin(np.outer(np.arccos(xasub),nd))) * nd
```

Answer (score 1):

I've replicated your MATLAB code with:

```
N = 100.
n = np.arange(N+1).reshape(1,-1)
x = np.cos(np.pi*n/N).T
xsub = x[1:-1,:]
T = np.cos(np.arccos(x)*n)  # broadcasted outer product
Tsub = T[1:-1,:]
dT = np.dot(np.sin(np.arccos(x)*n), np.diag(n.flat))
# np.diag needs 1d input to generate 2d array
# this is a case of matrix multiplication, the np.dot for array
# * for np.matrix
```

continuing

```
temp = np.dot(np.diag(xsub.flat), np.sin(np.arccos(xsub)*n))
temp = np.dot(Tsub, np.diag(n.flat)) - temp
temp = np.dot(temp, np.diag(n.flat))
d2Tsub = np.dot(np.diag((1/np.sqrt(1-xsub**2)).flat), temp))
```

messy, but runs and generates matching value.  Use of `np.matrix` versions of these arrays might simplify the appearance, as would cleaning up the repeated `np.diag(...flat)`.

for the rest of `d2T`, this `vstack` is a pretty literal translation.

```
d2T1 = ((-1)**n) * (n**2-1) * (n**2)/3
d2T2 = (n**2-1) * (n**2)/3
d2T = np.vstack([d2T1, d2Tsub, d2T2])
```

last step is a matrix divide.  MATLAB has 2 versions:

```
D2 = np.linalg.solve(T, d2T)        # matlab T\d2T
D2 = np.linalg.solve(T.T, d2T.T).T  # matlab d2T/T
```

I worked out this last equivalence from the Octave docs for `Y/X` and `X\Y` .

This is a literal translation.  I'm not trying to understand what is going on, or to make it idiomatic `numpy`.

---

A partial simplification.  No need for matrix products to use diagonal matrices.  Simple (broadcasted) element multiplication is enough.

```
n = np.arange(N+1)
x = np.cos(np.pi*n/N)[:,None]
Xn = np.arccos(x)*n
T = np.cos(Xn)
dT = np.sin(Xn)*n

xsub = x[1:-1,:]
d2Tsub = ((1-xsub**2)**(-.5)) * (T[1:-1,:] * n - xsub * np.sin(Xn[1:-1,:]))
d2T2 = (n**2-1) * (n**2)/3
d2T1 = ((-1)**n) * d2T2
```

You could probably replace a lot of the `diag(n)*` in matlab with `n.*`  For example

```
dT = n.*sin(acos(x)*n);  # equals
dT = sin(acos(x)*n)*diag(n);
```

However, I tested this in Octave which now has broadcasting.  I'm not sure where MATLAB stands in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you have *all* arrays and *no* matrices:

```
xasub : <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
xc    : <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
xa    : <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
xmin  : <type 'int'>
LA    : <type 'module'>
na    : <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
nd    : <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
Tsub  : <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
np    : <type 'module'>
pi    : <type 'float'>
dTsub : <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
N     : <type 'int'>
T     : <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
sp    : <type 'module'>
xcsub : <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
n     : <type 'list'>
xmax  : <type 'int'>
x     : <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
dT    : <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

So you'll need to modify the last line to use `np.dot()` accordingly, for example (with horrible variable names):

```
#d2Tsub = np.diag(np.power((xasub*xasub-1),-1)) * (Tsub*nd - np.diag(xasub) * np.sin(np.outer(np.arccos(xasub),nd)))*nd * nd
d2T_1  = np.diag(np.power((xasub*xasub-1),-1))
d2T_2  = np.dot( np.diag(xasub), np.sin(np.outer(np.arccos(xasub),nd)) )

d2T_3  = np.dot(d2T_1, (Tsub*nd - d2T_2))

d2Tsub = np.dot(d2T_3, nd)

print d2Tsub.shape  # (99L,)
```

Of course, you could use the `a.dot(b)` syntax instead of `np.dot(a,b)` and save a tiny bit space.

Comment: What this gives is a vector for d2Tsub, what I want is a matrix (N-1)x(N+1) in size, with rows corresponding to different x values for Chebyshev polynomial extrema grid (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#Roots_and_extrema), with the 1st and (N+1) row missing as they are at the endpoints and the different columns different poly orders (1st column: 0th order, 2nd column: 1st order, 3rd: 2nd order, ... ). This is why I wanted matrix multiplication, matrix multiplication should create a matrix with the dimensions I wanted.

Comment: It gives a vector because you're matrix multiplying `d2T_3`, a (N-1)x(N+1) matrix by `nd`, a (N+1)x1 vector.

Comment: Ah. Well, sorry, I'm new to Numpy been using it for less than a week. I suspect I may have neglected some diagonal matrices with nd and the x arguments down their diagonals. I know in MATLAB what I used is this code:
`clear all
N=100; 

n=0:N;
x = cos(pi*n/N)'; 
xsub = x(2:N); 

T=cos(acos(x)*n); Tsub = T(2:N,:); 
dT = sin(acos(x)*n)*diag(n); 
d2Tsub = diag(1./sqrt(1-xsub.^2))*(Tsub*diag(n) - diag(xsub) * sin(acos(xsub)*n))*diag(n);

d2T = [(-1).^n.*(n.^2-1).*(n.^2)/3; d2Tsub; (n.^2-1).*(n.^2)/3];

D2=d2T/T;`

Comment: Could you add that MATLAB code to the original post?  It would easier to read.